# IKEA com product scraper

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to make a simple ikea com product page scraper. Here is what i got

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
function get_product() {
    $product_id ='702.642.81';
    $prod_id = preg_replace('/\./', '', $product_id); 
    $domain = 'http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/'.$prod_id.'/?type=xml&dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes';
    $html = curl($domain);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
    print_r($xml);
}
```

Which seems to be working.
Here is the fragment of the `get_product()` result

```
[products] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [product] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [URL] => /ru/ru/catalog/products/P70264281/
                [browseable] => true
                [partNumber] => P70264281
                [name] => ЛЕРХАМН 
                [nameswe] => SimpleXMLElement Object
```

But there is some products(product ids) giving empty response

```
[products] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )
```

The id of the product is 090.071.63. The original link for this product page(at ikea com) contains "S" before the product id `products/*S*09007163`.
So i tried adding "S" prefix at `$domain`and it did not help

But if i will follow this link http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/S09007163/?type=xml&dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes it shows me product data.

What is the problem? Maybe someone faced that before

Comment: why not include `S` into a product page url? Just refine this id leaving both letters and number.

Comment: Also in your curl() procedure you `return curl_exec($ch)` before `  curl_close($ch)` which means the second statement won't be executed. Just save the `curl_exec($ch)` result in a variable and return it after closing CURL handler.

Comment: i will give it a try

Comment: i tried adding "S" to a product page link and it did not work that's the weird part of this "scrapper"

Comment: you've got `*S*09007163` so you use `S09007163`; when you get `09007163` you insert `09007163` without `S`.

Comment: `09007163` for this particular id, the product page link has `S` in it `...products/S09007163`, i tried to parse that link but it did not worked.

Comment: this is really weird. Here, this code will output the product page

`$product_id = 'S09007163';
 $prod_id = preg_replace('/\./', '', $product_id); 
 $domain = 'http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/'.$product_id.'/';
 $res = curl($domain);
 print_r($res);`

But when i add `?type=xml`, to the `$domain` it does not work

Comment: @MancharyManchary,  *But when i add ?type=xml, to the $domain it does not work* - this might be cause some items are loaded thru other means than xml. Just scrape html and fetch needed data.

Comment: you were right, this product are need to be scraped from different url

Comment: not all the data are in xml format. IKEA might not have all its data in xml... Now both [html](http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/S09007163/) and [xml](http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/products/S09007163?type=xml&dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes) get loaded.

Comment: it is. i found nice idea of using mobile version links to find out package info etc

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing, but using [AutoIT3](http://autoitscript.com) combined with [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) as my toolchain.

My approach was:

- Scrape IKEAs page for "all products" and get links that contain "categories". This is for example beds, lamps, ...
- For each category, get links to product pages. These are also easy to find, because they have a certain class and end in an ikea number
- Finally for each product (I have about 200 category pages, and around 15200 products. May have missed a few, but that's OK for now), download the product page. This has a large JSON block, which contains everything for the product. I can extract data from here on demand, such as manuals, images, ...

So basically I worked my way top-down, saving each list locally to avoid sending too much traffic to Ikea.

Final step will be to process images and manuals.

Some notes:

- you get the JSON in the language you specify, example ikea.com/da/dk  or  /ru/ru
- URLs are neatly organized and built up in a nice hierarchy
- look around the javascript files, they contain lots of comments from developers at Ikea. Fun to have  a small peek behind the curtain.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps a bit by reducing the scraping and parsing part of getting product information.

Someone reverse engineered the IKEA mobile app to see where the requests are going and found a public API endpoint which returns JSON data for a single product.

Unfortunatly the product you’re searching (090.071.63) was not available anymore but I was able to find out that this had been a desk called "LERHAMN" which is available and has the product id 20444256.

```sh
curl \
  --location \
  --request GET 'https://securema2.ikea.com/catalog/v2/ru/ru/product/ART,20444256' \
  --header 'Contract: 28292' \
  --header 'Consumer: IRAA'
```

Returns

```json
[
  {
    "ItemNo": "20444256",
    "ItemNoGlobal": "40444255",
    "ItemType": "ART",
    "ProductName": "ЛЕРХАМН",
    "ProductTypeName": "Стол",
    "ValidDesignText": "светлая морилка антик, белая морилка",
    "OnlineSellable": "false",
    "OnlineRange": "false",
    "BreathTakingItem": "false",
    "ItemUnitCode": "PIECES",
    "NewsType": "",
    "ItemNumberOfPackages": "2",
    "AssemblyCode": "Y",
    "DesignerNameComm": "Nike Karlsson",
    "ItemMeasureReferenceTextMetric": "118x74 см",
    "ItemMeasureReferenceTextImperial": "46 1/2x29 1/8 дюйм",
    "ItemPriceUnitFactorMetric": "",
    "ItemPriceUnitFactorImperial": "",
    "PresentationGroupCodeEn": "",
    "UnitPriceGroupCode": "",
    "PriceUnitTextMetric": "",
    "PriceUnitTextImperial": "",
    "PriceUnitTextMetricEn": "",
    "PriceUnitTextImperialEn": "",
    "RetailItemRating": {},
    "GPRItemOrigin": "52068",
    "GlobalisationContext": {
      "CountryCodeIso": "ru",
      "LanguageCodeIso": "ru"
    },
    "ClassUnitKey": {
      "ClassType": "GR",
      "ClassUnitType": "RU",
      "ClassUnitCode": "RU"
    },
    "RetailItemFilterAttributeList": {
      "RetailItemFilterAttribute": [
        {
          "FilterAttributeType": "Colour",
          "FilterAttributeTypeName": "Цвет",
          "FilterAttributeValueList": {
            "FilterAttributeValue": [
              {
                "FilterAttributeValueId": "10156",
                "FilterAttributeValueName": "белый"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemCareInstructionList": {
      "RetailItemCareInstruction": []
    },
    "RetailItemCommPriceList": {
      "RetailItemCommPrice": [
        {
          "RetailPriceType": "RegularSalesUnitPrice",
          "Price": "5499",
          "PriceExclTax": "4582.5",
          "CurrencyCode": "RUB",
          "ValidFromDateTime": "",
          "ValidToDateTime": "",
          "ReasonCode": "",
          "MaximumRetailPrice": "",
          "ComparableUnitPrice": {
            "UnitPriceMetric": "",
            "UnitPriceMetricExclTax": "",
            "UnitPriceImperial": "",
            "UnitPriceImperialExclTax": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "GPRCommSelectionCriteriaSelectionList": {
      "GPRCommSelectionCriteriaSelection": [
        {
          "SelectionCriteriaCode": "COLOUR",
          "SelectionCriteriaName": "цвет",
          "SelectionCriteriaValue": "светлая морилка антик/белая морилка"
        },
        {
          "SelectionCriteriaCode": "SIZE",
          "SelectionCriteriaName": "размеры",
          "SelectionCriteriaValue": "118x74 см"
        }
      ]
    },
    "AttributeGroupList": {
      "AttributeGroup": [
        {
          "GroupName": "SEO",
          "AttributeList": {
            "Attribute": [
              {
                "Name": "DESCRIPTION",
                "Value": "IKEA - ЛЕРХАМН, Стол, светлая морилка антик/белая морилка, 118x74 см , Компактный стол – идеальное решение даже для небольшого помещения.Массив сосны – прочный натуральный материал, который со временем выглядит только лучше.Поверхность, покрытая проз"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemCustomerBenefitList": {
      "RetailItemCustomerBenefit": [
        {
          "CustomerBenefitText": "Компактный стол – идеальное решение даже для небольшого помещения.",
          "SortNo": "1"
        },
        {
          "CustomerBenefitText": "Массив сосны – прочный натуральный материал, который со временем выглядит только лучше.",
          "SortNo": "2"
        },
        {
          "CustomerBenefitText": "Поверхность, покрытая прозрачным лаком, проста в уходе.",
          "SortNo": "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemCustomerMaterialList": {
      "RetailItemCustomerMaterial": [
        {
          "ProductTypeText": "",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "RetailItemPartMaterialList": {
            "RetailItemPartMaterial": [
              {
                "MaterialText": "Массив сосны, Морилка, Прозрачный акриловый лак",
                "PartText": "",
                "SortNo": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemLongBenefitList": {
      "RetailItemLongBenefit": []
    },
    "RetailItemGoodToKnowList": {
      "RetailItemGoodToKnow": [
        {
          "GoodToKnowTypeNameEn": "Purchase-/Other information",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "GoodToKnowText": "На 4 человека."
        },
        {
          "GoodToKnowTypeNameEn": "Purchase-/Other information",
          "SortNo": "2",
          "GoodToKnowText": "Рекомендуется использовать только в помещении."
        },
        {
          "GoodToKnowTypeNameEn": "Compl. assembly information",
          "SortNo": "3",
          "GoodToKnowText": "Для обеспечения максимального качества при необходимости подтягивайте шурупы."
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemCustomerEnvironmentList": {
      "RetailItemCustomerEnvironment": {
        "SortNo": "1",
        "RetailItemEnvironmentTextList": [
          {
            "EnvironmentText": "Пригодно для переработки или энергетической утилизации, если это предусмотрено в вашем регионе.",
            "SortNo": "1"
          },
          {
            "EnvironmentText": "В ИКЕА мы предъявляем строгие требования к древесине и не используем сырье из нелегально вырубленных лесов. К 2020 году вся древесина будет поставляться из сертифицированных лесных хозяйств, или будет использовано переработанное сырье.",
            "SortNo": "2"
          },
          {
            "EnvironmentText": "100 % возобновляемый материал (кроме креплений).",
            "SortNo": "3"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "RetailItemCommPackageMeasureList": {
      "RetailItemCommPackageMeasure": [
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "14 ¾ дюйм",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "38 см",
          "PackageMeasureType": "WIDTH",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "2 дюйм",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "5 см",
          "PackageMeasureType": "HEIGHT",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "43 ½ дюйм",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "110 см",
          "PackageMeasureType": "LENGTH",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "16 фнт 7 унц",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "7.45 кг",
          "PackageMeasureType": "WEIGHT",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "1"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "30 дюйм",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "77 см",
          "PackageMeasureType": "WIDTH",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "2"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "1 дюйм",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "3 см",
          "PackageMeasureType": "HEIGHT",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "2"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "47 ½ дюйм",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "121 см",
          "PackageMeasureType": "LENGTH",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "2"
        },
        {
          "SortNo": "1",
          "PackageMeasureTextImperial": "19 фнт 13 унц",
          "PackageMeasureTextMetric": "9.00 кг",
          "PackageMeasureType": "WEIGHT",
          "ConsumerPackNumber": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemCommMeasureList": {
      "RetailItemCommMeasure": [
        {
          "ItemMeasureTypeName": "Длина",
          "ItemMeasureTextMetric": "118 см",
          "ItemMeasureTextImperial": "46 1/2 дюйм",
          "SortNo": "1"
        },
        {
          "ItemMeasureTypeName": "Ширина",
          "ItemMeasureTextMetric": "74 см",
          "ItemMeasureTextImperial": "29 1/8 дюйм",
          "SortNo": "2"
        },
        {
          "ItemMeasureTypeName": "Высота",
          "ItemMeasureTextMetric": "75 см",
          "ItemMeasureTextImperial": "29 1/2 дюйм",
          "SortNo": "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemFeeList": {
      "RetailItemFee": []
    },
    "RetailItemTechnicalInformationGroupList": {
      "RetailItemTechnicalInformationGroup": []
    },
    "CatalogRefList": {
      "CatalogRef": [
        {
          "Catalog": {
            "CatalogId": "genericproducts",
            "CatalogName": "Товары",
            "CatalogUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/genericproducts"
          },
          "CatalogElementList": {
            "CatalogElement": [
              {
                "CatalogElementId": "52068",
                "CatalogElementType": "GENERIC PRODUCT",
                "CatalogElementName": "name",
                "CatalogElementUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/genericproducts/52068"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Catalog": {
            "CatalogId": "departments",
            "CatalogName": "Отделы",
            "CatalogUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/departments"
          },
          "CatalogElementList": {
            "CatalogElement": [
              {
                "CatalogElementId": "21826",
                "CatalogElementType": "CHAPTER",
                "CatalogElementName": "Столы до 4 мест",
                "CatalogElementUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/departments/dining/21826"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "Catalog": {
            "CatalogId": "functional",
            "CatalogName": "Функциональный",
            "CatalogUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/functional"
          },
          "CatalogElementList": {
            "CatalogElement": [
              {
                "CatalogElementId": "21826",
                "CatalogElementType": "CHAPTER",
                "CatalogElementName": "Столы до 4 мест",
                "CatalogElementUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/functional/10368/21826"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "CatalogElementRelationList": {
      "CatalogElementRelation": [
        {
          "CatalogElementId": "30360920",
          "CatalogElementType": "ART",
          "CatalogElementName": "ЛЕРХАМН",
          "CatalogElementRelationSemantic": "MAY_BE_COMPLETED_WITH"
        },
        {
          "CatalogElementId": "80334226",
          "CatalogElementType": "ART",
          "CatalogElementName": "КАУСТБИ",
          "CatalogElementRelationSemantic": "MAY_BE_COMPLETED_WITH"
        },
        {
          "CatalogElementId": "50407988",
          "CatalogElementType": "ART",
          "CatalogElementName": "ВИСТОФТ",
          "CatalogElementRelationSemantic": "MAY_BE_COMPLETED_WITH"
        },
        {
          "CatalogElementId": "60399803",
          "CatalogElementType": "ART",
          "CatalogElementName": "ХЕКТАР",
          "CatalogElementRelationSemantic": "MAY_BE_COMPLETED_WITH"
        }
      ]
    },
    "DemandList": {
      "Demand": []
    },
    "RetailItemImageList": {
      "RetailItemImage": [
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S1",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0238239_PE377693_S1.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "40",
          "ImageHeight": "40",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S2",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0238239_PE377693_S2.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "110",
          "ImageHeight": "110",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0238239_PE377693_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0238239_PE377693_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0238239_PE377693_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "PRICE TAG",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0238524.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "ImageType": "LINE DRAWING"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0744759_PE743386_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "2",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0744759_PE743386_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "2",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0744759_PE743386_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "2",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0745196_PE743621_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "3",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0745196_PE743621_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "3",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0745196_PE743621_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "3",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0908279_PH159442_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "4",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0908279_PH159442_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "4",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0908279_PH159442_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "4",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0732510_PE738650_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "5",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0732510_PE738650_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "5",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0732510_PE738650_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "5",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0719940_PH134863_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "6",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0719940_PH134863_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "6",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0719940_PH134863_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "6",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0871644_PE594929_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "7",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0871644_PE594929_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "7",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0871644_PE594929_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "7",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S3",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0870035_PE598860_S3.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "250",
          "ImageHeight": "250",
          "SortNo": "8",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S4",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0870035_PE598860_S4.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "500",
          "ImageHeight": "500",
          "SortNo": "8",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        },
        {
          "ImageUsage": "INTERNET",
          "ImageSize": "S5",
          "ImageUrl": "/ru/ru/images/products/lerhamn-stol__0870035_PE598860_S5.JPG",
          "ImageWidth": "2000",
          "ImageHeight": "2000",
          "SortNo": "8",
          "ImageType": "PICTURE SINGLE"
        }
      ]
    },
    "RetailItemCommAttachmentList": {
      "RetailItemCommAttachment": [
        {
          "AttachmentType": "ASSEMBLY_INSTRUCTION",
          "AttachmentUrl": "/ru/ru/assembly_instructions/lerhamn-stol__AA-2135389-4_pub.pdf",
          "SortNo": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    "GPRCommSelectionCriteriaList": {
      "GPRCommSelectionCriteria": [
        {
          "SelectionCriteriaCode": "COLOUR",
          "SelectionCriteriaName": "цвет",
          "SortNo": "1",
          "GPRCommSelectionCriteriaValueList": {
            "GPRCommSelectionCriteraValue": [
              {
                "SelectionCriteriaValue": "светлая морилка антик/белая морилка",
                "ItemRefList": {
                  "ItemRef": [
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "40444260",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,40444260"
                    },
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "20444256",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,20444256"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "SelectionCriteriaValue": "черно-коричневый",
                "ItemRefList": {
                  "ItemRef": [
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "30444307",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,30444307"
                    },
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "40444302",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,40444302"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "SelectionCriteriaCode": "SIZE",
          "SelectionCriteriaName": "размеры",
          "SortNo": "2",
          "GPRCommSelectionCriteriaValueList": {
            "GPRCommSelectionCriteraValue": [
              {
                "SelectionCriteriaValue": "118x74 см",
                "ItemRefList": {
                  "ItemRef": [
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "20444256",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,20444256"
                    },
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "40444302",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,40444302"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "SelectionCriteriaValue": "74x74 см",
                "ItemRefList": {
                  "ItemRef": [
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "40444260",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,40444260"
                    },
                    {
                      "ItemNo": "30444307",
                      "ItemType": "ART",
                      "ItemUrl": "/retail/iows/ru/ru/catalog/items/art,30444307"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Unfortunatly this endpoint doesn't seem to be very reliable. When a product is listed in a countries store’s website it’s not sure that the endpoint will return data for that product. It’s also not guaranteed that requesting the information in another language always works.

Btw. the "S" in front of a product code seemes to be a hint that the product is a "SPR" not an "ART" producttype. There’s also "SCI" product type but not clear when to use that.

Comment: This does not work. Maybe it used to, but not anymore